# I need power for a 240 volt a/c unit and electrical for 120 volt outlet

Tags: electrical

I have #8 - 2 wire with ground from the house panel to a 2 breaker sub panel. I am using a 240 2 pole breaker from the sub panel to the outlet. Did I need another (3) insulted wire for this to work? The other breaker in sub panel is for 120 volt outlets. Thanks

Comment: Adding pictures of both panels showing the wires/breakers will help.  So far it seems like you do need to rewire, but need more information.

Comment: Can you post photos of the inside of the subpanel in question please?

Answer (score 1):

I am understanding this to mean that the sub panel has two 120 volt legs for 240 volts and a ground. You will need to pull a third wire, if in conduit, for the neutral if you want a 120 volt outlet. If the feed to the sub panel is NM cable, you'll need to replace the cable.